# Find the limit superior of an enumeration of an interval in the rational numbers

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

How would I go about finding lim sup $a_n$, where $\{a_n\}$ is an enumeration of the rationals in the interval $[0,1]$? Honestly, I don't even know where to start.

Comment: For any $\epsilon\gt 0$, there is an infinite subsequence of $\{a_n\}$ such that each member of the subsequence is greater than $1-\epsilon$.

Comment: I can understand why that would be true, but how does that help me?

Comment: I was trying not to give it away entirely! More concretely, there is an infinite subsequence with limit $1$, so the limsup is $1$.

Comment: Wouldn't the same be true for some other point on the interval, say 1/2? Sorry, I'm just doing my best to grasp what is going on.

Comment: It is true for $1/2$, but the limsup is the largest possible limit of a subsequence.

Comment: Ah, of course. I think I'm starting to get it now, thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. A fair number of the problems you are asked to do become clear once the meaning of the words has been internalized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $\varepsilon>0$,the numbers $1-\dfrac1n$ such that $1-\varepsilon<1-\dfrac1n<1$ are an infinity, hence for any enumeration of the rationals in $[0,1]$, an infinity of them are in the enumeration with an index as large as we please. Thus $\limsup a_n=1$.